# Can I inherit structs in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'd like to inherit structs because these structs are very redundant. Only `id` is different:

```
#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
struct Movie {
    id: i32,
    title: String,
    director: String,
    releaseYear: i16,
    genre: String,
}

#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
struct MovieInsert  {
    title: String,
    director: String,
    releaseYear: i16,
    genre: String,
}
```

Why do I define these structs? When I GET JSON data from the database, I can convert like this:

```
let movie = request.json_as::<MovieInsert>().unwrap();
```

When I insert JSON data by POST, I can convert like this.

```
let movies = conn.query("select id, title, releaseYear, director, genre from movie", &[]).unwrap();
let mut v: Vec<Movie> = vec![];

for row in &movies {
    let movie = Movie {
        id: row.get(0),
        title: row.get(1),
        releaseYear: row.get(2),
        director: row.get(3),
        genre: row.get(4),
    };

    v.push(movie);
}

let json_obj = json::encode(&v).unwrap();
```

Could you tell me how to inherit structs or other good practice for this situation?

it is my inserting code.
if I change `let movie = request.json_as::<MovieInsert>().unwrap();`
to `let movie = request.json_as::<Movie>().unwrap();`,
it failed.
`MovieInsert` to `Movie`

```
// insert
{
    let conn = shared_connection.clone();
    router.post("/api/movies", middleware! { |request, mut response|
        let conn = conn.lock().unwrap();
        let stmt = match conn.prepare("insert into movie (title, releaseYear, director, genre)
            values ($1, $2, $3, $4)") {
            Ok(stmt) => stmt,
            Err(e) => {
                return response.send(format!("Preparing query failed: {}", e));
            }
        };

        let movie = request.json_as::<MovieInsert>().unwrap();
        match stmt.execute(&[
            &movie.title.to_string(),
            &movie.releaseYear,
            &movie.director.to_string(),
            &movie.genre.to_string()
        ]) {
            Ok(v) => println!("Inserting movie was Success."),
            Err(e) => println!("Inserting movie failed. => {:?}", e),
        };
    });
}
```

**Tried(Obsolated practice)**

```
extern crate serialize;
use std::default::Default;

use serialize::{json, Decodable, Decoder};

#[deriving(Encodable, Decodable, Show)]
struct Movie {
    _id: Option<i32>,
    title: String,
    director: String,
    releaseYear: i16,
    genre: String,
}

impl<S: Decoder<E>, E> Decodable<S, E> for Movie {
    fn decode(decoder: &mut S) -> Result<Movie, E> {
        decoder.read_struct("root", 0, |decoder| {
            decoder.read_struct_field("data", 0, |decoder| {
                Ok(Person{
                    age: try!(decoder.read_struct_field("_id", -1, |decoder| Decodable::decode(decoder)))
                })
            })
        })
    }
}
```

However, `Show` doesn't exist ``#[derive]`for custom traits is not stable enough for use and is subject to change (see issue #29644)
src/main.rs:28 #[derive(Encodable, Decodable, Show)]`

Later I changed `deriving` to `derive`.

`warning: derive(Decodable) is deprecated in favor of derive(RustcDecodable)
src/main.rs:28 #[derive(Encodable, Decodable, Show)]`

`RustcDecodable` was good. Decodable was obsolated..

### Finally

I just changed type of `_id`

```
#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
struct Movie {
    _id: Option<i32>,
    title: String,
    director: String,
    releaseYear: i16,
    genre: String,
}
```

Comment: What is `MovieInsert` *for*? It’s just a `Movie` without the ID? You should probably think about remodelling things in some way; hard to suggest things without much more information.

Comment: yes. It’s just a Movie without the ID? because, if I insert sql by POST, it doesn't have id yes so `let movie = request.json_as::<MovieInsert>().unwrap();` failed

Comment: I added code for inserting

Comment: Inheritance wouldn’t be a good solution to this anyway; you’ll doubtless want other permutations of fields at a later date, e.g. the fields one is allowed to update may vary by permissions, and so on. You’re definitely not dealing with a case where inheritance would be *honest*, even if it would—for this basic case—work. If you did it, you’d regret it later.

Comment: I think `MovieInsert` avoids solving the real problem which is how you're decoding the JSON. You can either write a custom decoder for `Movie` or I believe you can declare id as type Option<i32> (not sure about this). Here's a good article on implementing custom deserialization: http://valve.github.io/blog/2014/08/26/json-serialization-in-rust-part-2/

Comment: Thank you fore replying. I read your github.io link.  `#[deriving(Encodable, Decodable, Show)]` is obsoleted isn't it? `impl` also doesn't needed.
Finally, I just changed `_id: Option<i32>,`

Comment: The tutorial is a bit outdated but the implementation of decode is still relevant. I'm glad you were able to solve your problem!

Comment: @shepmaster Given that the RFC about struct inheritance mentioned in the duplicate (http://aturon.github.io/blog/2015/09/18/reuse/) has been merged, would anyone mind if I asked a canonical question "How do I do this struct inheritance thing?"

Comment: @bright-star which RFC are you talking about? Please link to the [merged RFC in the repo](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs).

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210